# RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding Java encryption - Issue with node.js equivalent

Tags: node.js, encryption

I'm building a node.js app that needs to send some encrypted data to a server. This data must be encrypted using a given public key (.pem format). Using the java code presented below I'm able to successfully encrypt the data however when using a similar code on node.js the encrypted data is considered as invalid by the server. I also tried using node-rsa but without much luck :\

Did anyone ever have this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Java Code sample:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1PADDING");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKeys);
byte[] encryptedText = cipher.doFinal(textToEncrypt.getBytes());
String encryptedTextFinal = Base64.encodeBase64String(encryptedText);
return encryptedTextFinal;

Same code on Node.js:

function encryptWithPubKey(dataToEncrypt) {
 const absolutePath = path.resolve(publicKeyPath)
 const pubKey = fs.readFileSync(absolutePath, 'utf8')
 const buffer = Buffer.from(dataToEncrypt, 'base64')
 const encrypted = crypto.publicEncrypt({key: pubKey, padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_PADDING}, buffer)
 return encrypted.toString('base64')
}
```

Comment: The encodings of the plaintexts do not match: In the Java code the default encoding is used, but in the NodeJS code Base64. To ensure that the codes are functionally identical, the same encodings must be applied: If the default encoding in the Java code is e.g. UTF8, in the NodeJS code `Buffer.from(dataToEncrypt, 'utf8')` or in short `Buffer.from(dataToEncrypt)` must be used. By the way, in the Java code the encoding should be specified explicitly e.g. with `textToEncrypt.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`.

Comment: In node.js you base64 encode the text before encryption .. which you don't do in your java

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answers but unfortunatly it didn't solve the issue :\ If I remove the base64 encoding the server does not accept the request at all. With the encoding it accepts the request but returns a mismatch error (I'm using this for authentication purposes). I think that the decryption on the server side, for some reason, fails because I'm encrypting the text in a different way than the expected and when it gets there is different from the original one.

Comment: Is the input for both methods identical, i.e. is `textToEncrypt` equal to `dataToEncrypt`? If not, you should explain the difference.

Comment: I'm sending the exact same string on both methods, that's why it's so weird. Perhaps there are some slight differences in the encryption algorithm used by Java and by Crypto, I don't see what else can be different here :\

Comment: Have you also specified the encoding in the Java code or tested which encoding is used? I cannot reproduce the issue with my tests (as long as both codes use the same encoding). The ciphertext delivered by both methods can be decrypted with the same method.

Comment: For a repro you could post a test key pair, your plaintext and the results of both methods.

Comment: Hmm, no, I did nothing different on both methods. Same string, same encoding, same everything. I tried several encodings here Buffer.from(dataToEncrypt, 'base64') just to see if I got different results but the server only accepts the request when I use the base64 encoding. If i use something than base64 it returns a server error. Using Java I don't need to encode the message first, but on Node.js apparently I have to.

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce the issue for identical encodings with my data (key pair, plaintext, ciphertexts). As I said, test data provided by you would still be an option.

Comment: Hi, found the issue! The code was after all working properly but one of the parameters had to be an encrypted byte sequence instead of an encrypted string (ex.: crypto.randomBytes(32) instead of "normal_string"). I changed to byte sequence and the server responded as it should. Thanks for your answers, they helped me find the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Solution to your problem:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/NoPadding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKeys);
byte[] encryptedText = cipher.doFinal(textToEncrypt.getBytes());
String encryptedTextFinal = Base64.encodeBase64String(encryptedText);
return encryptedTextFinal;
```

Same code on Node.js:

```
function encryptWithPubKey(dataToEncrypt) {
  const absolutePath = path.resolve(publicKeyPath)
  const pubKey = fs.readFileSync(absolutePath, 'utf8')
  const buffer = Buffer.from(dataToEncrypt, 'base64')
  const encrypted = crypto.publicEncrypt({key: pubKey, padding: crypto.constants.RSA_NO_PADDING}, buffer)
  return encrypted.toString('base64')
}
```

Simpler Code:
Create a Cipher With NoPadding. Don't use this in production.

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.*;
import java.util.Base64;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // Generate a new RSA key pair
    KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
    KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();

    // Get the private key as a string
    PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
    System.out.println("Private Key");
    System.out.println(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(privateKey.getEncoded()));

    // Get the public key as a string
    PublicKey publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();
    System.out.println("Public Key");
    System.out.println(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(publicKey.getEncoded()));

    // Encrypt the message using the private key
    String message = "Hello, World!";
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/NoPadding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
    byte[] encryptedMessage = cipher.doFinal(message.getBytes());

    // Transmit the encrypted message and the public key string to the Node.js side
    System.out.println("Encrypted message: " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encryptedMessage));
  }
}
```

In NodeJs you can use decrypt without padding. Using the public key from the Java Program I decrypted in NodeJs

```
const crypto = require('crypto')
publicKeyString = '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAkpcXDapUKExVugabuetO+XUuhqQtBaWx1rlvgDI/BIwIFcf21phzM1H1qc/yXFF6mn8k4pM+E8iJeD7BAPKXbVeYpjH/6Lj21IGOe95wO664jX6/AAHB9FyBHglMEnMCXQQPxMPcVh4f9gcYhSuJnzmnH05Ryp3NS68fYGBODKwPld01K8lfnIuisvasytR+7ALGeDrB0LXQfqw48xoaXtbv627XxI6PyeJTPRdRQuCo3h6Fc6Q6KPhXf7ZlXBtgftTfu457svT7uQXHnWy6SsGz/rj229RatR7G/olV22atyqT9dS+RiXdlC/j8sDZt/OQL7VGme6X3V2759wZBZQIDAQAB\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----'
publicKey = crypto.createPublicKey({key: Buffer.from(publicKeyString)})
encrypted_msg = 'EUQBSw4H+J3ZqKskrq8kfmXDQiURsFXsfAuIH8bRYo4k0Ke1E2QD8WrAAIOmtum5KHYXcfxfDK3krWZepyjWO1hsva6e8efyOR7UL8nJhD/fzxLzihkB5pdTPUf8sCKyrQ6aZS6rLghTabWjVyzXuwPB7PY/pk68cCstxyLy+WwNFcXcPHnhypMux9EZK++kffpcUyfBG18ucTq+XdTMAsP/ongBJi9ImjE6lDorvfKgVRYkN+WhWHXe0izPCrz4cG68gvyn0ypmdGi33Amk8s40o7E5msB5e+qszpG+wN2xr04wcvELx5CwrMWU5Jh3xJOGM+SNWdrz/3m+xUf3MA=='
output = crypto.publicDecrypt({key: publicKey, padding: crypto.constants.RSA_NO_PADDING}, Buffer.from(encrypted_msg, 'base64'))
console.log(String(output))
```